# Predicting mean smooth in GAM with multiple continuous and categorical "by" variables

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I use a GAM to model interactions between two continuous and one unordered categorical factor with three levels. Depending on significance of the smooth terms I would like to extract and visualize either level-specific smooth predictions if they are significant, or the interaction between the two continuous variables across all levels is, in case this one is signficant.

Using the iris dataset here because it is pretty close to my own data, which contains different species and their traits as predictors and matings as reponse (I am trying to model fitness landscapes). I specified the model below in an attempt to exclude the other terms (e.g., using `predict.gam(mod1, newdata, exclude=c( "ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width):Speciessetosa", "ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width):Speciesversicolor", "ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width):Speciesvirginica")`, if this makes sense (see below):

```
## data
data(iris)

## gam
mod1 = gam(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width * Species + 
         s(Sepal.Length, k=3) +
         s(Sepal.Length, by=Species, k=3) +
         s(Sepal.Width, k=3) +
         s(Sepal.Width, by=Species, k=3) +
         ti(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, k=3) +
         ti(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, by=Species, k=3),
       method = "REML",
       data=iris
)
> anova(mod1)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width * Species + s(Sepal.Length, 
    k = 3) + s(Sepal.Length, by = Species, k = 3) + s(Sepal.Width, 
    k = 3) + s(Sepal.Width, by = Species, k = 3) + ti(Sepal.Length, 
    Sepal.Width, k = 3) + ti(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, by = Species, 
    k = 3)

Parametric Terms:
                                 df       F  p-value
Sepal.Length                      1 4.30623 0.039860
Sepal.Width                       1     NaN      NaN
Species                           0     NaN      NaN
Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width          1 4.10032 0.044835
Sepal.Length:Species              2 0.94772 0.390174
Sepal.Width:Species               0     NaN      NaN
Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width:Species  2 1.02435 0.361785

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                                          edf         Ref.df        F   p-value
s(Sepal.Length)                                1.000000528612 1.000001005439 11.22252 0.0010463
s(Sepal.Length):Speciessetosa                  1.000000232442 1.000000464223  4.81234 0.0299554
s(Sepal.Length):Speciesversicolor              0.000001331420 0.000002637874  0.04797 0.9997172
s(Sepal.Length):Speciesvirginica               1.000000996148 1.000001892404  2.09408 0.1501724
s(Sepal.Width)                                 1.000007172805 1.000012865152  3.19529 0.0760765
s(Sepal.Width):Speciessetosa                   1.000000855121 1.000001708770  0.10222 0.7496783
s(Sepal.Width):Speciesversicolor               1.665759568126 1.888265235757  1.03729 0.2710795
s(Sepal.Width):Speciesvirginica                0.641978333598 0.870807147692  2.25871 0.1630554
ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)                   0.873528400557 0.982977416832  7.70746 0.0067218
ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width):Speciessetosa     0.000001845268 0.000003682513  0.00065 0.5000000
ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width):Speciesversicolor 0.000002545775 0.000005019515  0.03278 0.9996770
ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width):Speciesvirginica  0.000003049801 0.000005392319  0.08124 0.9994726
```

So, considering these results, I would like to visualize the smooth for `s(Sepal.Length):Speciessetosa` separately from `s(Sepal.Length)`, because the smooth effect is significant, but also `ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)` because the across-species smooth is significant, unlike the by-species terms.

**Does this model specification make sense both in the context of i) my research question (do species differ in how their trait interaction-surfaces affect the response var) and ii) to selectively extract smooth surfaces within and across categorical levels?**

Related:

- [Predicting mean smooth in GAM with smooth-by-random-factor interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189384)
- [Predicting with GAM (mgcv) and categorical/factor covariate in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608112)
- [How do I fix a categorical predictor at a mean value when predicting from a regression model with multiple categorical predictors in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499923)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model as you have it doesn't make much sense.

1. why do you have linear terms and their interactions for length and width with species? The bases for the smooths already include those terms.
2. why are you setting `k` so low here - you're only allowing two degrees of freedom per smooth here. (Is this just an limitation of this example data set?)

Making statistical decisions in the way you plan using *p* values isn't advisable; you need to consider the potential effect sizes too. So I would suggest that you visualise all smooths.

I'm not sure what the problem is because `plot(mod1)` will plot all the smooths allowing you to see the average effect of the smooth for sepal length separately from the species-specific smooth of that same covariate. You can use the `select` argument to choose only the terms you want to plot (`select` uses the numeric order of the smooths as shown in the output from `summary()`). `gratia::draw()` will also allow the same plots.

The smooth interaction complicates things a bit, as the effect of sepal length is contained in the average smooth and the interaction. The way to proceed here is to prepare a counter factual and predict from the model at evenly space values of sepal length, while holding the sepal width fixed at some representative value. Then you also select which smooths you want in the counterfactual prediction:

```r
# packages
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")
## data
data(iris)

## model
mod1 <- gam(Petal.Width ~ Species + 
         s(Sepal.Length, k=4) +
         s(Sepal.Length, by=Species, k=4) +
         s(Sepal.Width, k=4) +
         s(Sepal.Width, by=Species, k=4) +
         ti(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, k=4) +
         ti(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, by=Species, k=4),
       method = "REML",
       data = iris)
```

Let's generate data for the counterfactual (here I'm fixing this at Sepal.Width at 2.5 as the median value of the interaction is ~entirely flat)

```r
ds <- data_slice(mod1, Sepal.Length = evenly(Sepal.Length),
  Sepal.Width = 2.5)
```

This produces

```r
> ds                                                                          
# A tibble: 100 × 3
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1         4.3          2.5 setosa 
 2         4.34         2.5 setosa 
 3         4.37         2.5 setosa 
 4         4.41         2.5 setosa 
 5         4.45         2.5 setosa 
 6         4.48         2.5 setosa 
 7         4.52         2.5 setosa 
 8         4.55         2.5 setosa 
 9         4.59         2.5 setosa 
10         4.63         2.5 setosa 
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

and we see another problem; because the model contains the parametric effects for the individual species mean petal widths, the intercept if for the reference level (with the default contrasts). So you have to either accept this and note that the plots of the smooth effect of Sepal.Length is offset by some vertical amount that would differ if you looked at a different species, or show the smooth for all three species, or change the contrasts such that there is a different interpretation of the intercept (whether that makes any sense depends on the specific contrasts you choose). This is important, because this counterfactual will include the estimated average petal width for the reference species but we are not going to show the species-specific smooth effects as per your request.

Given that caveat, we proceed by using `predict` and here it makes more sense to *choose* which terms to include than to spell out all the terms you want to *exclude*, which we do with the `terms` argument:

```r
sm_want <- c("(Intercept)", "s(Sepal.Width)",
  "ti(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)")
fv <- fitted_values(mod1, data = ds, terms = sm_want)
```

which produces

```r
> fv                                                                          
# A tibble: 100 × 7
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species fitted    se  lower upper
          <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1         4.3          2.5 setosa  -0.222 0.212 -0.638 0.193
 2         4.34         2.5 setosa  -0.219 0.209 -0.628 0.191
 3         4.37         2.5 setosa  -0.215 0.206 -0.619 0.189
 4         4.41         2.5 setosa  -0.211 0.203 -0.609 0.187
 5         4.45         2.5 setosa  -0.207 0.201 -0.600 0.186
 6         4.48         2.5 setosa  -0.203 0.198 -0.591 0.185
 7         4.52         2.5 setosa  -0.200 0.196 -0.583 0.184
 8         4.55         2.5 setosa  -0.196 0.193 -0.574 0.183
 9         4.59         2.5 setosa  -0.192 0.191 -0.566 0.182
10         4.63         2.5 setosa  -0.188 0.189 -0.558 0.182
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

(Note that we ignored the `Species` parametric term here so this counterfactual data set is for `setosa` we would have to double check that this is the reference level - it is here, but you could add `Species = ref_level(Species)` to the `data_slice()` call above to be explicit about which species we are considering in the counterfactual.)

Now we can plot

```r
library("ggplot2")

fv |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

This produces

[image]

Wherein the figure shows the smooth effect of the sepal length on the response petal width, at a sepal width of 2.5 for *Iris setosa*.

Hope this answer explains how to plot the smooth you wanted?

As for the model specification I address that at the start (what you have is wrong as you are including the linear components twice (hence [in part] the `NaN`s).

This model (even corrected) doesn't answer your research question; you would need to fit a model without the species-specific effects (surfaces) and then compare the two models with a generalised likelihood ratio test or AIC for a test of the more complex model over the simpler model. Or you can try to estimate the difference between the estimated surfaces for pairs of species.

Doing that in general is relatively easy (I have a blog post on the general idea [shown only for univariate smooths] [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/)). *gratia* has a function `difference_smooths()` for this but something isn't working with your specific model right now that I'll need to look at and fix.

Comment: still processing your answer, but already have a first question: I thought to understand linear vs non-linear patterns I would have to include linear terms in additions to the smooths? asked differently, when does it makes sense to include a variable as a linear term?

Comment: @mluerig the smooth functions already contain the linear functions within the span of the functions representable by their basis, so you don't need to include them separately. It doesn't make sense to include linear terms for the same variables that you have included also as smooth terms. The one situation you might do it is if you want to test for wiggliness beyond a linear effect, but then you have to remove the linear function form the basis, for example `y ~ x + s(x, bs="tp", m=c(2,0))` where the 0 means zero null space, & which is only available for the default thin plate spline basis

Comment: following up on the comment: "testing for wiggliness beyond a linear effect" is what I want, because otherwise I'd simply use linear models - so I guess I'll update the models accordingly. can I remove the linear function from the basis of a tensor smooth in the same fashion as for a spline (e.g. "ti(x,y, bs="tp", m=c(2,0)"?

Comment: regarding question i): "Making statistical decisions in the way you plan using p values isn't advisable ... " -  I wonder which statistical decisions you refer to. I simply wish to first test for non-linear within-species interactive effects (tensor product), and if there are none, for non-linear across-species interactive effects (tensor product), and if there are none, linear within-species interactive effects (linear interaction), and so on for the univariate terms. This should be fine if accompanied by adequate visualization and effect sizes in a table, no?

Comment: regarding question ii): "I'm not sure what the problem is because plot(mod1) will plot all the smooths allowing you to see the average effect of the smooth for sepal length separately from the species-specific smooth of that same covariate. " - Yes, but for that average effect this'll only work if I include "ti(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)" without 'by="species"'.  (1/2)

Comment: It appears that in mgcv, in order to test/visualize such two-way interaction between continuous and categorical variables, I have to make this an extra term in the model (as you and I have done above). Put differently: if this were a linear model, I could inspect the two-way interaction of Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width in the model summary without having to specify it explicitly (I could just do Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width * Species), and I could pull out the marginal effects for "Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width" across all species. (2/2)

Comment: Re comment on Q1: you shouldn't be doing statistical testing like this: if p value of wiggly bit < 0.05 assume wiggly otherwise assume linear. You should be estimating the functional relationship and present the estimated function and its associated uncertainty. The way you are suggesting to do this would say this is exactly linear if P > 0.05, and as such, all else equal, you'll bias your results to keeping the wiggly bit in extreme data sets and drop it otherwise, which will lead to biased estimates. Better to just estimate the function and leave it alone

Comment: Oh, you meant the average interaction effect? Also there are lots of ways to specify smooth-factor interactions and estimate averaged effects with GAMs in mgcv. For example: https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876 & there is the `sz` basis that wasn't available when we wrote that paper. If you want the average effect over species, then you need to include it in a model. You could only pull out <q>the marginal effects for "Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width" across all species</q> by statistically averaging the effects over species; there's nothing stopping you doing that with emmeans or marginaleffects say

Comment: "you shouldn't be doing statistical testing like this: if p value of wiggly bit < 0.05 assume wiggly otherwise assume linear." - ok that's fair, but if p value of wiggly bit > 0.05 and linear <0.05 and it looks like mostly a flat line (or an uncurved plane for tensors), it's fairly safe to assume it's a linear relationship, no? and re. "you'll bias your results to keeping the wiggly bit in extreme data sets and drop it otherwise": I think this was a misunderstanding - I never intended to drop anything. I just want to be able to say "more wiggly, more linear, nothing at all"

Comment: @mluerig then just quote the EDF of the estimated function; EDF = 1 == linear, EDF > 1 = wiggly.